# Download failes for chuncked file in browser Elixir

Tags: elixir, cowboy, plug

Apparently it looks like I am missing something to add in my code. I am sending a chunked HTTP response and with content type `text/csv` so that if I open it in the browser it should download. But it fails to download and I have no idea about its solution as I am learning elixir. Here is the code which I am trying. Can you please help me out on this.

```
get "/dbs/foo/tables/source" do
  conn
  |> put_resp_content_type("text/csv")
  |> send_chunked(206)
  |> foo_data
end


  defp foo_data(conn) do
    Enum.reduce_while(["every-","word-","is-","a-","chunk"], conn, fn (chunk, conn) ->
      case Plug.Conn.chunk(conn, chunk) do
        {:ok, conn} ->
          {:cont, conn}
        {:error, :closed} ->
          {:halt, conn}
      end
    end)
  end
```

**postman**

[image: postman screenshot]

**chrome**

[image: chrome screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find out what I was doing wrong. I was sending status code `206` instead of `200`. Credit goes to @NobbZ (Slack) who pointed me out. After changing the status code it is working as expected.